# php regex named groups

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

can someone tell me how to use named groups syntax in PHP?

I'm trying  to parse a simple math equation, for example `someVariable!=someValue`.
I'd like to get 3 values from matching operation, stored in 3 variable `variable`, `operator`, `value`.

Comment: Use a parser to parse math / equations. Using regexes for those is not only error-prone, it will also be a lot harder.

Comment: **See also:** https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677485/regex-named-capturing-groups-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this basically what you're looking for?

```
$equation = 'someVariable!=someValue';
$matches = array();
preg_match('~^(\w+)([!=]+)(\w+)$~', $equation, $matches);

$variable = $matches[1];
$operator = $matches[2];
$value = $matches[3];
```

The actual regular expression is pretty silly, but I assume you already have that part figured out.

Comment: See also example 4 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php if you are looking for named subpatterns

Comment: Actually I need to match any logical operator, and ignore the quotations (single or double) if they surround the value, but thats basically what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: There are no "named capture groups" in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

see 'subpatterns' and 'back references'

Comment: Also: http://jonaquino.blogspot.com/2007/12/php-regular-expressions-recursion-named.html

Comment: This link-only hint (answer) could have been a comment under the question.