# Regex to extract weather forecast, and add to an array

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've bought RegexBuddy, given it a try and unless I am matching on something static, and simple - I just can't *get regex*!

What I am trying to do is from the following line of text; I would like to extract tidal information into an associative array.

`High Tide:  2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and  2.4m on Tue at 09.18am`

And end up with the following array:

```
[0] =
  'Day' => 'Mon',
  'Time' => '8.54pm',
  'Height' => '2.0m',
  'Tide' => 'High'

[1] =
  'Day' => 'Tue',
  'Time' => '09.18am',
  'Height' => '2.4m',
  'Tide' => 'High'
```

The concept I am struggling most with is the fact that there are multiple matches that I wish to extract (e.g. 2.0m and 2.4m). I've managed to match on 2.0m, and 2.4m, but how do I determine which one is which? (First High tide vs second high tide).

Any hints?

Comment: where did you get the information that on Tue the tide is "Low"?

Comment: "Hide Tide:" is always present, so you can assume that the information immediately following is the hide tide. Everything after the "and" is then the second high tide for the day. In other words "Hide tide:  ", "on", "at", "and", "on", "at" are always present and static.

Comment: Actually, I may have fluffed. That line of text is for the two high tides in a day. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am";

preg_match_all("~((High|Low) Tide:)? (\d.\dm) on (\w{3}) at (.{7})~", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($matches);
```

outputs

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm' (length=33)
      1 => string 'High Tide:' (length=10)
      2 => string 'High' (length=4)
      3 => string '2.0m' (length=4)
      4 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
      5 => string '08.54pm' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string ' 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am' (length=23)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '2.4m' (length=4)
      4 => string 'Tue' (length=3)
      5 => string '09.18am' (length=7)
```

i probably got the thing about the low tide wrong so here is some code without the tide

```
$string = "High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am";

preg_match_all("~(\d.\dm) on (\w{3}) at (.{7})~", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($matches);
```

outputs:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm' (length=22)
      1 => string '2.0m' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
      3 => string '08.54pm' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '2.4m on Tue at 09.18am' (length=22)
      1 => string '2.4m' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Tue' (length=3)
      3 => string '09.18am' (length=7)
```

Comment: ! Thanks. Your answer is what I've accepted in the end as with slight modifications I was able to get exactly what I was after, with minimal regex to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If the word `and` always separates the two tides, you could break the string in two and process each half separately.  For example:

```
$str = "High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am";
$data = explode(" and ", $str);

$result = array();
foreach($data as $tide)
{
    $result[] = parseWithRegex($tide);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can used [named groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109424/php-regex-named-groups) and then refer to what you captured by name: `(?P<name>exp)` => `$yourVarName['name']`

(not tested, but this would be the idea)

```
/^[^\d]+(?P<heightOne>[\d\.]+?m)\son\s(?P<dayOne>\w+?)\sat\s(?P<timeOne>.*?(am|pm))\sand\s(?P<heightTwo>[\d\.]+?m)\son\s(?P<dayTwo>\w+?)\sat\s(?P<timeTwo>.*?(am|pm))$/
```

Comment: You show the named group format correctly but in your regex you're doing `?P:<heightOne>`

Comment: @sweaver2112 Thanks! I don't just want to copy your code and run, so give me a bit to look it over, understand how it's working, and will report back (and accept) accordingly.

Comment: I apologize in advance for the bugs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) to get an associative array with the result and the pattern to match the string is pretty straight forward.

`/(?P<tide>high|low)\s+tide:\s+(?P<height1>\d+\.\d+m)\s+on\s+(?P<day1>[a-z]+)\s+at\s+(?P<time1>\d+\.\d+[ap]m)\s+and\s+(?P<height2>\d+\.\d+m)\s+on\s+(?P<day2>[a-z]+)\s+at\s+(?P<time2>\d+\.\d+[ap]m)/i`

Example script:

```
$string = "High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am";

// named groups will also assign matches associative to the matches array, e.g. (?P<tide>high|low) will set $matches["tide"] to 'low' or 'high'
preg_match(
        '/
            (?P<tide>high|low)                      # match and capture string "high" or "low"
            \s+tide:\s+                             # match string "tide" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<height1>\d+\.\d+m)                  # match and capture one or more digits followed by a dot and one or more digits followed by an m
            \s+on\s+                                # match string "on" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<day1>[a-z]+)                        # match one or more letters
            \s+at\s+                                # match string "at" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<time1>\d+\.\d+[ap]m)                # match and capture one or more digits followed by a dot and one or more digits followed by an a or p, and string "m", so am or pm
            \s+and\s+                               # match string "and" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<height2>\d+\.\d+m)                  # match and capture one or more digits followed by a dot and one or more digits followed by an m
            \s+on\s+                                # match string "on" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<day2>[a-z]+)                        # match one or more letters
            \s+at\s+                                # match string "at" surrounded with one or more spaces on each side
            (?P<time2>\d+\.\d+[ap]m)                # match and capture one or more digits followed by a dot and one or more digits followed by an a or p, and string "m", so am or pm
        /ix', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

this will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => High Tide: 2.0m on Mon at 08.54pm and 2.4m on Tue at 09.18am
    [tide] => High
    [1] => High
    [height1] => 2.0m
    [2] => 2.0m
    [day1] => Mon
    [3] => Mon
    [time1] => 08.54pm
    [4] => 08.54pm
    [height2] => 2.4m
    [5] => 2.4m
    [day2] => Tue
    [6] => Tue
    [time2] => 09.18am
    [7] => 09.18am
)
```