# RegEx Named Capturing Groups in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex to capture a list of numbers (it will be more complex than this eventually):

```
$list = '10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1';

$regex = 
<<<REGEX
    /(?x)
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<number> (\d+) )
        (?<list> (?&number)(,(?&number))* )
    )
    ^(?&list)/
REGEX;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match($regex,$list,$matches)==1) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 )
```

How do I capture the individual numbers in the list in the $matches array? I don't seem to be able to do it, despite putting a capturing group around the digits (\d+).

**EDIT**

Just to make it clearer, I want to eventually use recursion, so **explode** is not ideal:

```
$match = 
<<<REGEX
    /(?x)
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<number> (\d+) )
        (?<member> (?&number)|(?&list) )
        (?<list> \( ((?&number)|(?&member))(,(?&member))* \) ) 
    )
    ^(?&list)/
REGEX;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a `(?(DEFINE)...)` section is only to define named sub-patterns you can use later in the define section itself or in the main pattern. Since these sub-patterns are not defined in the main pattern they don't capture anything, and a reference `(?&number)` is only a kind of alias for the sub-pattern `\d+` and doesn't capture anything too.

Example with the string: `1abcde2`

If I use this pattern: `/^(?<num>\d).....(?&num)$/` only `1` is captured in the group *num*, `(?&num)` doesn't capture anything, it's only an alias for `\d`.
`/^(?<num>\d).....\d$/` produces exactly the same result.

An other point to clarify. With PCRE (the PHP regex engine), a capture group (named or not) can only store one value, even if you repeat it.

The main problem of your approach is that you are trying to do two things at the same time:

1. you want to check the format of the string.
2. you want to extract an unknown number of items.

Doing this is only possible in particular situations, but impossible in general.

For example, with a flat list like: `$list = '10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1';` where there are no nested elements, you can use a function like `preg_match_all` to reuse the same pattern several times in this way:

```
if (preg_match_all('~\G(\d+)(,|$)~', $list, $matches) && !end($matches[2])) {
    // \G ensures that results are contiguous
    // you have all the items in $matches[1] 
    // if the last item of $matches[2] is empty, this means
    // that the end of the string is reached and the string
    // format is correct
    echo '<°)))))))>';
}
```

Now if you have a nested list like `$list = '10,9,(8,(7,6),5),4,(3,2),1';` and you want for example to check the format and to produce a tree structure like:

```
[ 10, 9, [ 8, [ 7, 6 ], 5 ], 4 , [ 3, 2 ], 1 ]
```

You can't do it with a single pass. You need one pattern to check the whole string format and an other pattern to extract elements (and a recursive function to use it).

`<<<FORGET_THIS_IMMEDIATELY`

As an aside you can do it with `eval` and `strtr`, but it's a very dirty and dangerous way:

```
eval('$result=[' . strtr($list, '()', '[]') . '];');
```

`FORGET_THIS_IMMEDIATELY;`

Comment: Thanks for that, at least I know it's not possible. Reading around, It looks like only .NET regex captures all the repeating groups. Still, recursive matching is quite powerful!

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips: The new python regex module is able to do that too.

Comment: You can actually capture the second number be adding another set of parenthesis, as in /^(?<num>\d).....((?&num))$/, however, the second group will be captured as \2, i.e. not named.

Comment: @RudigerW.: obviously, but it was just an example to illustrate the fact that a backreference isn't a capture.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get an array of the comma delimited numbers, then explode:

```
$numbers = explode(',', $matches[0]); //first parameter is your delimiter what the string will be split up by. And the second parameter is the initial string
print_r($numbers);
```

output:

```
Array(
    [0] => 10,
    [1] => 9,
    [2] => 8,
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

For this simple list, this would be enough (if you have to use a regular expression):

```
$string = '10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1';
$pattern = '/([\d]+),?/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```